# Unable to compile bibliography in Ubuntu-TexStudio

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
I installed texlive using the command `sudo apt-get install texlive`
I then ran `sudo apt-get install texstudio`.

I have a TeX file and a Reference file.
I have named the Reference file as References.bib and the TeX file as main.tex.

I have used the following command to run the References file

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
```

But whenever I compile the TeX file main.tex I am getting the following error message :

```
File `biblatex.sty' not found. \addbibresource
```

Can someone please help me on how to get it fixed?

Though the TeX file ran on my laptop, its not running in my University computer.
I need to submit  my assignment but I dont know what to do now?

I will be grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Maybe only a part of the package database is installed with `apt-get`? To install entire texlive quickly, I would suggest download DVD image from [here](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images/) and install locally.

Comment: Consider the  full vanilla installation as suggested by moewe. It is not as easy as `apt-get install whatever`,  but  nothing  specially complex for an average Linux user.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install texlive` only pulls in a subset of the packages available in TeX live. If you want to use `biblatex` and Biber you need to install additional packages.

1. Run `sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra` [to install `biblatex`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/texlive-bibtex-extra).
2. Run `sudo apt-get install biber` [to install Biber](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/biber).
3. Configure TeXstudio (or any other editor you might use) to run Biber instead of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).
4. Compile your document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your preferred flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...), see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for more explanations.

---

If you want to be able to use all of TeX live without having to worry about installing missing packages you can install [`texlive-full`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/texlive-full) to pull in everything TeX live has to offer. Naturally that takes up quite a bit of space, which may or may not be an issue for you.

---

Note that the TeX live versions in the Ubuntu repositories are essentially frozen forever. This means that you will not get updates to any packages. Furthermore, the Ubuntu and TeX live release cycle usually line up in a way that causes Ubuntu x.04 to have TeX live 2000+(x-1). This is not always an issue, but especially towards the end of an LTS release, the TeX live packages can be quite seriously outdated.

If you want to live at the edge of current development, you can install a 'vanilla' TeX live from TUG.org, see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864).